# static variables in Symfony2 controller

Tags: php, symfony

I think I need some static variables but can't get an example to work. I'm a fairly experienced web developper, mostly in Java so Php is secondary for me. I know about session variables, but these do not fill my needs for this case. Here, I need a set of variables to be global and shared between different sessions / clients. So, I digged a bit and it seemed what would do the job are static variables. It does not need to be that way but it seemed the simplest.

So, here's a simple example, but it fails. It's simply a counter which I expected was constantly going to increase, but the result I constantly get is 2, as if it was initialized on each page request:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
public static $counter = 1;

public function testAction() {
    self::$counter++;
    }
}
```

So my question is why is this not working as expected? Is there another way I could achieve this using some Symfony2 object perhaps, I did not find anything yet looking at the docs.

-- Added --

Thanks for the comments so far. So, let me put it this way then. The goal I'm trying to achieve is to have global variables but not constants, I want to be able to edit these at runtime. I know I could do this with either a database or serializing to disk, but these complicate the setup a bit and I'd  like to keep it really minimal. Using an external storage just seems like a workaround... So, if I'm to stay with a pure PHP/Symfony2 way, this can't be done? In java, and I hate to compare things like that so please keep it on topic, but the server software will keep running until the process is shut down, so yes it is possible to have global variables which you can edit in such a manner. Plus it's possible to have class variables which will remain in existence outside of http requests, so I thought I might be able to do the same. Thanks again, in worst case, I'll just use database or serialize to file, the workaround...

-- Added again --

On hold, unclear? At least leave a comment if so, I'd be happy to provide further details / clarifications if needed but I took a while to revisit my post, provide details and study the possible solutions myself. Otherwise, this is just sad and useless... If there's perhaps no way to achieve this, at least I will know and stop wondering.

Comment: If it's static, you're not supposed to change the value. You can define some [global variables](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html) to use in your Twig templates, but the value can't be changed.

Comment: PHP is not Java. PHP static variables are global variables in a shared-nothing architecture. After the request those are gone. Store it in the database and write a service for getting / setting that variable, bundle it up, configure it and you're done sf2 style.

Comment: Is the example from the question really gonna work in Java?

Comment: I mean, I never heard about a language that can get memory for constantly increasing variable with eternal lifetime

Comment: Thanks all! FYI I've added a small section to my question...

Comment: You could [register a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container) class that holds your static variables. Iirc that should be instanciated as a singleton and will be available across your controllers.

Comment: @RoyalBg - yes it should work. In java static means that a variable exists outside of class instances. You might need that to keep a handy reference to a singleton instance for example or perhaps a counter of instances of a given class. And yes you would have a eternally increasing variable, which would eventually overgrow its allocated memory. Memory leaks are often an issue with Java software, so in general static variables are evil and discouraged unless necessary...

Comment: On hold because unclear?!? Let me try again then, I need global variables (editable by program at runtime, not constants), accessible regardless of which session / request. Can that be done without a "hack", using some PHP / Symfony2 feature, and without relying to external storage (databases or serializing to file)?

Comment: I don't think the question is necessarily unclear - but @hakre is correct - the PHP lifecycle lasts one request so you will have to have to persist those values some other way - file, database, cache etc. If you are using PHP <= 5.4 with APC you could use `apc_store()` for instance: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php

Comment: @zeartist it cannot be done, because unlike in Java, when there is no request begin processed, PHP is not running at all, it is the web server (maybe Apache) that is always running and maintaining its state. You must use something external from PHP/Symfony2.

Comment: @zeartist However Symfony2 makes it easy to store things in external storage. It's not really a "hack" to use the file system.

Comment: Thanks a ton guys, makes sence. And yes it is fairly easy to store using external storage, which is how I ended up fixing this issue in my case (json + file). I'll look at apc cache, might come handy, otherwise it's fairly fast to write data to a file using json serialization.